# distances in alternative basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let's say i have 2 points X and Y, 
the standard basis B and an alternative basis B' such that :

$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        \vdots \\
        x_n \\
        \end{pmatrix}
,
Y = \begin{pmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        \vdots \\
        y_n \\
        \end{pmatrix}
,
B_{std} = I_n
    ,
B' = \begin{pmatrix}
        & & & \\
        [e_1']_{std} & [e_2']_{std} & \cdots & [e_n']_{std} \\
& & &
        \end{pmatrix} 
$

the distance between X and Y under $B_{std}$ is :

$d^2_{AB} = (Y-X)^T (Y-X)$

And i think the distance between X and Y under B' is :

$d^2_{AB} = (Y-X)^T M (Y-X)$

for some positive definite matrix M.

I calculated $M = B^T B'^{-1 T}B'^{-1}B$, am I correct ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "distance under $B'$?" Why should the distance of two points depend on the way we represent these points?

Comment: obvioulsy let's say the alternative system of axis for R^2 is (2 0 ; 0 2) then the distances are twice smaller

Comment: So you're talking about the distances of the coordinate vectors and not of the vectors themselves? To rephrase it: You're not interested in the distance between two points $A$ and $B$, but rather in the distance between their representations on a given map, correct?

Comment: if iunderstood you correctly, yeah that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=Y-X$ and express $u=\sum e'_iu'^i$. The coordinate representation of the both sides in the standard basis is [u]=B'[u']. Omitting the brackets, $u^Tu=(B'u')^T(B'u')=u'^TMu'$ with $M=B'^TB.$

Comment: ok thanks, that confirms what i thought